# Inserting node into sorted linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to insert a node into a sorted linked list. The list has a dummy node.

```
void add(Node **nodeArray, int setNumber) {
    char userString[5];
    Node *head = nodeArray[setNumber];      /* head pointer to first element of array (dummy) */
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));   /* new node to be added to array */
    Node *tmp = head;

    printf("Please enter some data: ");
    scanf("%s", userString);

    strncpy(newNode->data, userString, DATA_SIZE);  /* copies string entered by the user to data field of new node */
    newNode->next = NULL;   /* initializes next field of new node to NULL */



    while (tmp->next) 
        tmp = tmp->next;        /* points head to next element in list */
    tmp->next = newNode;    /* adds element to list */
}
```

This inserts a node at the end of the list. I understand the logic of the added sort. You look ahead to the next node and if the new node is less than the next, you point the new node to the next node and the previous node to the new node. Can someone help me implement this in code. This is what I have so far, but does not work.

```
if (!tmp->next)
    tmp->next = newNode;
else {
    while (tmp->next) {
        if (strcmpa((tmp->next)->data, newNode->data) < 0) {
            newNode->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = newNode;
        } //else if (strcmpa((tmp->next)->data, newNode->data) > 0) {
            //tmp->next = newNode;
        //}
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Here is the compare function:

```
int strcmpa(char *s1, char *s2) {
   while (*s1 && tolower(*s1) == tolower(*s2))
   {
      s1++;
      s2++;
   }
   return tolower(*s1) - tolower(*s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there but `tmp->next` should be redirected to `newNode` itself, not to `newNode->next`. Actually, that's a no-operation, because at the time of that command, `newNode->next` is what `tmp->next` was and you're reassigning a value that's already there.

What you want is that `tmp`, having pointed to `X`, points to `next` instead, which then only points to `X`. So, formally,

```
X = tmp->next;
tmp->next = newNode;
newNode->next = X;
```

which can be condensed to

```
newNode->next = tmp->next; /* using the X where originally stored */
tmp->next = newNode; /* rewriting that memory has to wait till now */
```

---

**Update:** The above code links `newNode` after `tmp` (as I thought that was what you needed). But in the sorted list, you find the first `tmp` that needs to appear after your node, so you need to go before that. This brings two problems:

1. You need to modify what the item *before* `tmp` points to, because the new node will go there, so you need to keep one more variable,
2. sometimes you'll need to put the new node in the very beginning, which has no previous node.

On the plus side, the above also handles `!tmp->next` (insertion at the end) gracefully so you don't really need another branch for that case.

It will look something like

```
Node* head = (whatever);
Node* prev = NULL;
Node* tmp;

for(tmp = head; tmp && strcmpa(tmp->data, newNode->data) < 0; tmp = tmp->next) {
    prev = tmp;
}

/* now tmp points to the first larger node or to NULL and prev is its preceding node.
 * If there's none (if the head is already larger) then prev = NULL. */

if(prev == NULL) {
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode; /* Don't forget to update this in the array where you took head from! */
} else {
    newNode->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = newNode;
}
```

This works also if `head` was `NULL` and creates a linked list with a single entry.

---

This focused on the insertion. Regarding the rest of your code (originally posted as comments):

- The program will fail if you overrun the `userString` buffer on the unrestricted `%s` `scanf`. Set a limit.
- With a limit, you don't need the unsafe `strncpy`. Use a normal `strcpy` that guarantees it will null-terminate your string.
- Your `strcmpa` looks fine. But do make sure `tolower()` does what you expect it to with an input of `'\0'`. This compares the strings correctly:

  ```
  char toLower(char in) { 
    if(in >= 'A' && in <= 'Z')
      return in + 'a' - 'A';
    else
      return in;
  }
  ```

Comment: I edited my code how you suggested. It is not inserting the node in the correct position though. See edited code above.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's inserting one node later, isn't it? That will require a bigger rewrite, so please confirm before I commence that.

Comment: Actually I just debugged it and it seems that the compare function that I'm using isn't quite doing what it needs to do. I'll edit the question to show the function. It's not comparing correctly so it just skips over that conditional statement.

Comment: @namarino See updated. I tested it a bit (but only with `strcmp`).